# android JSON how to sms details

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent

I am creating a mobile app, basically I have a Json which stores information about certain results, basically if I want to SMS a friend the details of those results, when I click on SMS to a friend button, I want it to take me to androids SMS application with the text from my Json in the body already, and then I can just enter the number or look at contacts and send it. 
I want to know if anybody has a tutorial or some good resource on how to do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String uri= "smsto:"+phoneNumber;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", Json.tostring);
            intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what are you storing in + phoneNumber?

Comment: yes, you can even ignore it, as per your requirement, you need to choose from contact list...